# Excel Count Items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum up a spread sheet based on certain criteria I can filter the rows and preform a sum but I'm trying to figure out a formula that will satisfy the search criteria.

For example I'd like to sum up the Head column given the following conditions are met Block= Block C, Level=Basement, Column Type= C2, Head=0=<15

The same formula would be modified for various parameters Ground floor etc & Head=16=<30

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-conditional counting`COUNTIFS` is the most efficient function, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Block C",B:B,"Basement",F:F,"C2",D:D,">15",D:D,"<=30")`

You can reference whole columns with no significant loss of efficiency here because with `COUNTIFS` excel will calculate just using the "used range"